# How to pass information from a query string to a page tab app in Facebook using just Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to pass a single piece of information (using a query string) to my Facebook page tab application.

For example, if the user clicks on this URL:

-http://apps.facebook.com/myappname/?app_data=mydata

I would want to be able to access 'mydata' in the app.

From the reading I've done, Facebook does not allow `GET` requests, but it's possible to do this using `app_data` and `signed_request`.

However, I have not been able to find any information on how to set this up using the javascript SDK (is that even possible?) and .NET (ideally, I would be able to implement this with just JavaScript). I have no idea how to set up and read data using a signed_request, and the documentation around signed_requests is confusing me more than helping. I would really like simple instructions on how to implement this feature.

EDIT:

I think I've almost figured it out. In case anyone else is looking for an answer to this, I put what I did so far below. Also, if you see any room for improvement please let me know. I don't claim this is perfect by any means, but it works.

First, the url needs to be the page tab url, not the direct url to the app (like I posted above):
-http://www.facebook.com/pages/PageName/########?sk=app_#########&app_data=mydata

Here is the javascript code that is working for me:

```
//get value of signed request and split it 
var signedRequest = $('#mainContent_hfSigned').val().split(".");

//decode json (this does not work on ie - needs to be replaced)
var decodedJson = window.atob(signedRequest[1]);

//parse json to gain access to parameters
var jsonParams = jQuery.parseJSON(decodedJson);

//append the app_data varible to ensure it's being read properly
$('.message').append('Your app_data param is "' + jsonParams.app_data + '"')
```

On jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/C3xsm/1/

One thing I know I still need to do is replace atob with a base64url decoder for javascript. I'm thinking about using this one:

http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/trunk/javascript/base64.js

If it works well, I'll update it here. Or if anyone knows of something that works better, please let me know.

Comment: You're on the right track. My advice is do more research. There are plenty of code examples out there for this stuff...

Answer (score 0):

> ideally, I would be able to implement this with just JavaScript

That’s not possible, because as you already found out the signed_request parameter is POSTed to your page, and JavaScript has no access to POST parameters itself.

The documentation on the [signed_request parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) has instructions on how to parse/decode it server-side; the example is in PHP, but it should be easy to transfer the basic algorithm (if you can call it that) to your .NET environment.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify: it is a POST request, but facebook posts it to a hidden input field so that javascript does have access to it.

Comment: What hidden field? Sorry, I don’t see what you mean.

Comment: It's okay. Facebook uses the information from the post request and puts it into an encrypted hidden input field on page tab apps. It looks something like this:                        `<input type="hidden" value="jV3rcGKTBMhy5E6kzz-KgW8bzRFvlMbeTIGevMir17A.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImFwcF9kYXRhIjoidXJsMSIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTM0Mzc1MzQzNiwicGFnZSI6eyJpZCI6IjQwMDUzOTU1MDAwNjEzMSIsImxpa2VkIjpmYWxzZSwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9LCJ1c2VyIjp7ImNvdW50cnkiOiJ1cyIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVuX1VTIiwiYWdlIjp7Im1pbiI6MjF9fX0" id="mainContent_hfSigned" name="ctl00$mainContent$hfSigned">`